# how to convert values to title case in jolt transform

Tags: apache-nifi, transformation, title, jolt

I need to convert all values of country to Title case like "Russia".

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mehari",
    "country": "russia",
    "age": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "Helen",
    "country": "Norway",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdu",
    "country": "India",
    "age": 30
  }
]
```

What I did

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "country": "=toTitleCase(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output:
no change.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mehari",
    "country": "russia",
    "age": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "Helen",
    "country": "Norway",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdu",
    "country": "India",
    "age": 30
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following JOLT spec can work in your case:

```json
[{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
            "country": "=split('',@(1,&))"
        }
    }
}, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
            "country": {
                "[0]": "=toUpper(@(0))"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
            "country": "=join('',@0)"
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Jolt only Provide string and mathematic operations like toLower, toUpper, concat, min / max / abs, toInteger, toDouble, toInt
so maybe its not possible to capitalize the content directly you have to aplly conditions in multiple steps like slice the whole string and uppercase the first character and then join it to remaning.